# Why can't I delete this contact in Android?

Tags: android

I can update a phone number like this:

```
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withSelection("_id =?", new String[] { id })
         .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "5555555555").build());

         getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

But where I update displayname, it doesn't work:

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
         .withSelection("_id=?", new String[] { id })
         .withValue("display_name", "jack").build());
```

This is neither word:

```
context.getContentResolver().update(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                values,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName._ID + "="
                        + id
                        + " and  mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/name'",
                null);
```

Comment: have you tried CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME instead of "display_name",

Comment: CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME and  Phone.NUMBER both is “data1” ，so how to distinguish?

Answer (score 2):

display_name is read-only.

Anyone who wants to do detailed work with the Contacts Provider should *definitely* read the Contacts Provider API guide and follow the Contacts Provider Android training. The Contacts provider is a complex database system with many rules, and you'll run into frustrating problems unless you understand the basic layout of the provider.

Both CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME and CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER are set to data1, because in fact they don't refer to separate tables. Instead, they both refer to column DATA1 in ContactContracts.Data. *All* detailed data for contacts is stored in ContactContracts.Data, regardless of what it is. For example, all phone numbers and all email addresses for a contact are stored in ContactContracts.Data. The way you tell one type of row from another is through the row's MIMETYPE value. The documentation explains this in detail.

Another hint: you should avoid doing additions, deletions, or updates to the Contacts Provider in your own code. Instead, send an Intent that starts the device's contacts app or allows the user to choose the contacts app to use. This allows the user to do the work in the contacts app rather than your app. This is also described in the documentation.